# The 10 minute ban bug

Tags: bug

We are not allowed to answer another question within 10 minutes of answering the first question or accept an answer within the same timeline. I find this feature quite good, but I have found a bug. I can easily pass this ban.

**How to get past the ban: Switch your IP.**

**How I found the bug:** The finding of bug was totally a co-incidence, since I practice ethical hacking I have a python code developed by me which changes my IP periodically within 5 minutes.

**Suggestion:** I think the stack exchange should ban the account from adding/accepting an answer instead of the IP address.

This ban can easily be overcame using free proxy software such as Ultrasurf, which renders this ban useless.

Comment: According to the [rate limit guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) it's 3 minutes for < 125 rep. I'm wondering if some time in the past you'd got hit by another rate limit (maybe a spammer had used the IP in the past for example) so you just had in mind from that it was 10 minutes?

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah probably, now that means you can get over any kind of rate limit just by switching IP.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your proposed solution would be easily defeated by a user creating additional "sock puppet" accounts, which happens often enough to be an issue.

A more robust solution would have to take both aspects into account, but this creates potential problems with multiple legitimate users who happen to be sharing IP addresses, which also happens regularly.

Comment: I agree with you, Fake users are always a big problem. We can't stop people from creating fake accounts can we? I think a more deep information should be asked which shall never be shared to 3rd party.